# using array_splice/array_merge

Tags: php, arrays

Hi need help in array_merge and array_splice
for example if array contains 10 elements need to splice first 6 after applying logic merge the arrays

```
   $input = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
 $array1 =   array_splice($input ,0, 6); // $input is now $array1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
 // $array = unset($array1[4]); example for logic
  // how to merge $array1 to remaining array value which was spliced 
 O/P: array(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
```

Comment: Use something like `array_merge(array_map(array_splice($input,0,6),'logicFunction'),array_splice($input,6,25));`

Comment: Do you want to "split" an array and merge it back after doing something with the parts?

Comment: question: can't you apply your logic straight on the first array?

Answer (score 1):

Using `array_splice` will split your array in two parts. Your input array is modified, then you've got the 'non-spliced' values in.

You can this specificity to merge it after :

```
$input = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
$array1 = array_splice($input ,0, 6);
$array2 = array_merge($array1, $input);

var_dump($array2);
```

See the first user contribution on `array_splice` doc : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php#106244

Comment: Do you mean http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php#106244?

Comment: Thanks @Herbert I was searching for an anchor ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_merge($arr1, $arr2, ...)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to merge the arrays.

```
$array1 = array_splice($input ,0, 6);
$array2 = $input

//do whatever you want with sub-array, and to merge them back, use:
$finalArr = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

where $array1, and $array2 are obtained from `array_splice(..)`